# Difference between parSequence and starting fibers manually

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have got two program's implementatnion

```
def program_valid: IO[Unit] = for {
    interpreter <- Interpreter[IO]
    fib1 <- display(interpreter).start
    fib2 <- read(interpreter).start
    _ <- fib1.join
    _ <- fib2.join
  } yield ()

  def program_invalid: IO[Unit] = for {
    interpreter <- Interpreter[IO]
    _ <- (read(interpreter), display(interpreter)).parSequence
  } yield ()
```

First one works perfectly well which means both fibers keep running (dispaly and read). Unfortunately second implementatnion works different. It looks like only the display fiber would run. Why it goes like that? What is the difference here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parSequence` is for collections *(well actually for types with an instance of `Traverse`)*, not sure how it even compiles; well I mean there is probably a `Traverse` instance for `Tuple2` but it definitively doesn't do what you want.

You may use:

```scala
_ <- (read(interpreter), display(interpreter)).parTupled.void
// Or
_ <- IO.both(read(interpreter), display(interpreter)).void
// Or
_ <- read(interpreter).both(display(interpreter)).void
// Or
_ <- List(read(interpreter), display(interpreter)).parSequence_
```